# What should I use instead of tocstyle?

Tags: tocstyle

I'm using `tocstyle` in my document:

```
% table of contents customizations:
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
\settocfeature{leaders}{\hfill}
```

Which gives me this warning:

```
Writing index file book.idx
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocstyle.sty

Package tocstyle Warning: THIS IS A DEPRECATED ALPHA VERSION!
(tocstyle)                USAGE OF THIS VERSION IS ON YOUR OWN RISK!
(tocstyle)                EVERYTHING MAY HAPPEN!
(tocstyle)                THE PACKAGE IS FROZEN WITH ALL IT'S BUGS!
(tocstyle)                IT WILL BE REMOVED FROM KOMA-SCRIPT SOON!
(tocstyle)                THERE IS NO SUPPORT, IF YOU USE THIS PACKAGE!
(tocstyle)                Maybe it would be better, not to load this package.
```

What should I use instead?

Comment: As suggested by the author of `tocstyle` on its [CTAN page](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle), "[`tocbasic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic) and [`scrwfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrwfile) should be used instead".

Comment: Another possibility could be tocloft

Comment: Although you should not use tocloft when using a KOMA class. In that case, tocbasic is a much better fit (and also inherits some of the tocstyle design choices).

Answer (score 3):

With a **KOMA-Script class** you should use `tocbasic`. Note that the KOMA-Script class loads `tocbasic` automatically.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2020/07/22]% needs KOMA-Script version 3.31
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  raggedentrytext,
  linefill=\hfill,
  numwidth=0pt,
  numsep=1ex,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  indent=0pt,
  dynindent
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\section{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

With a **standard class** you can use package `tocbasic`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}[2020/07/22]% needs KOMA-Script version 3.31
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  raggedentrytext,
  linefill=\hfill,
  numwidth=0pt,
  numsep=1ex,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  indent=0pt,
  dynindent
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indentfollows=chapter]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indentfollows=subsubsection]{tocline}{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\section{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]