# move from tocstyle to tocbasic

Tags: tocstyle, tocbasic, dotfill

I have been using tocstyle until it was removed.
Here is my definition

```
\usepackage[%
%%% toc width calculation 
  tocindentauto,     % all widths at the TOCs are calculated by tocindentauto
%%% indentation of toc
  tocgraduated,      % standard
%%%  page breaking rules
  tocbreaksstrict,   % sets a lot of penalties before and after TOC entries 
                     % to avoid page break between a TOC entry and it's parent. 
%%%  indentation of unnumbered TOC entries
  toctextentriesleft,   % indented as if they have an empty number.
]{tocstyle}
```

[image]

I have found [this definition for tocbasic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557571/what-should-i-use-instead-of-tocstyle) and changed the second line to \dotfill, but the dotted line is different to before

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
raggedentrytext,
linefill=\hfill,
numwidth=0pt,
numsep=1ex,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
linefill=\dotfill,
indent=0pt,
dynindent
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\bfseries}
```

So the question is how to restore the dotted line with spacing as in the first example?

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification: you want the dots to be further apart?

Comment: Something like `\renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{4.5}` ?

Comment: That changes the \dotfill for the whole document. I want a definition only for the section. How is the line defined in standard classes? Is there a command that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `tocbasic` provides `\TOCLineLeaderFill` for the dotted line between the entry text and the page number in TOC. So you could use

```latex
hfill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
```

But chapter entries without dots and other levels with dots are the default for `book` and `report` classes! Therefore you simple have to remove all your `hfill` settings to get the desired result.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  %raggedentrytext,
  numwidth=0pt,
  numsep=1ex,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter,figure,table}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  %raggedentrytext,
  numwidth=0pt,
  numsep=1ex,
  dynnumwidth,
  indent=0pt,
  dynindent,
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\bfseries}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Theory}
\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Subsection heading}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not use a KOMA-Script class, you have to load package `tocbasic` and have to declare that the `section` indent follows the `chapter` settings and the `paragraph` indent follows the indent and number width of `subsubsection` entries.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  indentfollows={chapter,subsubsection}
]{tocline}{section,paragraph}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  %raggedentrytext,
  numwidth=0pt,
  numsep=1ex,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter,figure,table}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  %raggedentrytext,
  numwidth=0pt,
  numsep=1ex,
  dynnumwidth,
  indent=0pt,
  dynindent,
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Theory}
\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Subsection heading}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The defintion of the dotted line in the `tocstyle` package was:

```
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
```

I am unsure whether it is a good idea to take over the exact defintion from this outdated package, but if you really want the identical thing, you can store this definition in a macro and use this instead of `\dotfill`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\def\mydotfill{\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
raggedentrytext,
linefill=\hfill,
numwidth=0pt,
numsep=1ex,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
linefill=\mydotfill,
indent=0pt,
dynindent
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{Two}
\subsection{Three}

\end{document}
```

[image]